# Can the golang plugin for IntelliJ give better type information?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, go

When I move the mouse cursor over the variable, I want it to tell me the specific data type, like LiteIDE does:

[image: LiteIDE behaviour.]

But the IntelliJ golang plugin is giving me data like:

[image]

Is there a better way to find out what type the variable is? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

at the moment this feature is not implemented in the plugin but I've opened a issue for it. If you want to track it, the please follow [this issue](https://github.com/go-lang-plugin-org/go-lang-idea-plugin/issues/2052)

Comment: Thanks. I installed a new version and it works. But I think you could do it better and better. For example, when the mouse is over the variable it will show me the type. But now I must press ctrl + shift + p or configure other key shortcut.  When the mouse is over a variable or a function, you can do anything here, not only show the variable type. It's a trigger chance here.

Answer (score 1):

You could position the cursor over `mask` and press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, quick lookup.

Comment: Thanks, it works. When I switch keyamp to  default XWin, it works. I usually use Eclipse (Mac OX) keymap, because I use Eclipse for writing c++ code. I don't want to use two different keymap.